# I'm having trouble with fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

In my app the user can select an image with a popup dialogue. The first time they do so everything works as expected, and during the addition of the image fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory is called and dir returns NO. However, when the user selects an image the second time fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory always returns YES (even if it is NOT a directory).

```
-(void) addImagesWithPath:(NSURL *)fileURL recursive:(BOOL) recursive{
  int i, n;
  BOOL dir;
  NSError *error;
  NSURL *newURL;

  [[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:[fileURL absoluteString] isDirectory:&dir];
```

EDIT: if I add "dir = NO" before the method call it seems to work, but it feels like a hack.

Comment: Are you checking the return value of `-fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:` prior to checking the contents of `dir`? It looks like you aren’t from the code in your question, and it’ll probably help if you list the complete/relevant code you’re using.

Comment: When I do check the return value it is ALWAYS false regardless of whether the file exists.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should **always** check the return value of `-[NSFileManager fileExistsAtPath:isDirectory:]` prior to inspecting the contents of the second (output) parameter. The output parameter is only meaningful if the method returns `YES`. This is described in the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/fileExistsAtPath%3aisDirectory%3a):

> Upon return, contains `YES` if path is a directory or if the final path element is a symbolic link that points to a directory, otherwise contains `NO`. **If path doesn’t exist, the return value is undefined.** Pass `NULL` if you do not need this information.

If the method returns `NO` then the path doesn’t exist or your application cannot access it. If it does exist, check whether your path is a full path (for instance, it shouldn’t start with `~`).

Also, you should be using `-[NSURL path]` instead of `-[NSURL absoluteString]` when passing paths to `NSFileManager`.